# how to turned off chunked encoding?

Tags: asp.net, iis, encoding, chunked-encoding

I want to turn off chunked encoding in my IIS webserver so I can get the content length, and I had turned off the chunked encoding in IIS webserver in IIS webserver feature as you can see below

[image]

but why is it even after I change the `Enable Chuncked Encoding` value to false, the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` still appear in Live HTTP header??[image]

so what happened?

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Were you / are you using JavaScript or communicating via a proxy?